# Android Device Chooser — device not showing up after computer format

Tags: android, eclipse

I have formatted my computer recently . After getting format my eclipse is not detecting my device(USB debbing etc are on).The same device is being detected in other pc eclipse.My pc is detecting my device the problem is with eclipse only. Device is moto g2. I have android sdk pckgs installed of version 5 and higher.

Comment: Sounds like perfect timing to migrate to Android Studio. You'll thank me later ;)
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: @Tapirboy no my programs are build in eclipse and i want to use eclipse only

Comment: Ok.. Maybe your are also using windows, and need to install the usb driver?

Comment: @Tapirboy But my pc is detecting my device so why should i download USB driver

Comment: Because you need adb to detect the usb too: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: @Tapirboy worked ..!!!! thanx dude :)

Comment: Sweet, no worries! =)